# Magento, Translate TAX and Subtotal on invoice PDF

Tags: magento, translate, invoices

I tried to search everywhere but could not find any solution to this question; I want to simply translate words subtotal and tax from the **total** PDF invoice generated by Magento. I already tried with csv but seem to have no effect. Where are these word stored?

I Remember that  words I just want the subtotal fees and translate from the total rportato invoice, in the table of objects are already ok

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

First you should copy from core to local and than make changes.
For translating, without the csv, you must edit app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php or any other php file from app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/ as per your need.